# How to print and view logs from Hyperledger Fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I want to see logs while calling functions in my chaincode, for debugging purposes. I tried something like this:

```
var logger = shim.NewLogger("chaincode_example02")
logger.Info("get_caller_data called");
```

I've viewed logs of the peer running the chaincode, but I couldn't find the above log. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/logging-control.md

Comment: Yes. I referred this link and came up with the code I wrote.

Comment: @cjcroix Sorry but I don't get what you mean by dev or net. I followed the instructions in this tutorial. Please have a look - [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/8d277a63-4204-4fd3-8cb8-b7cb222cd522/entry/Steps_to_setup_Blockchain_Hyperledger_Fabric_0_6_development_environment_on_Ubuntu?lang=en)

Comment: figured it out..thanks for the help!

Comment: For me, I use "docker attach <container id>" in case that I use fmt.Println instead of the logger.Info in my chaincode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you startup your chaincode in dev mode using a command like `./chaincode_example02`, then the log statements should be visible in the console where that same process is started.

If you deploy the chaincode in net mode then each peer starts up a docker container that is named something like `<networkId>-<peer enroll id>-<chaincode Id>` .You can view all the docker containers started up on a peer by using the command `docker ps`, and view the content of a log by using the command `docker logs <container id (get this from the previous command)>`